# How to add credit card numbers using Luhn's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm a new programming student and I'm trying a write an algorithm in Java that does the following:

Counts every other digit of a credit card number (starting with the second to last digit) and multiplies each digit by two.

Take the resulting integers and add all the digits together (i.e. if I got 14, 6 and 2, I'd add 1 + 4 + 6 + 2)

What I have so far is:

```
            for(i = creditCard.length() - 2; i >= 1; i = i - 2){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(creditCard.substring(i,i+1));
            String y = Integer.toString(x);

              for(j = 0; j < y.length() - 1; j++){
                int z = Character.getNumericValue(y.charAt(j));
                unselectedSum = unselectedSum + z;
            }
          }
```

This returns  0 as the `unselectedSum`.

Again, my programming knowledge is very limited, so I would appreciate any help i could get!

Comment: A pointer for further investigation. This usually happens if you try to access a location of an array/string beyond its boundaries.

Comment: can provide the complete stacktrace log along  with the complete code what you have implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you initialized the variable unselectedSum by 0 like:

```
int unselectedSum = 0;
```

What I can see from the fragment of your code is a few mistakes which you probably didn't intend to make. I will explain it with an example.

```
String creditCard = 1234567812345678;
```

For the first iteration of the outer loop, `creditCard.substring(i,i+1)` would return `7` because the `String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` method returns the string starting at `beginIndex` and ending at **`endIndex-1`**, both inclusive.

Next, in the inner loop, you're asking the loop to run till `j < y.length() - 1`.

Now, as the length of y is 1, so, the condition reduces to `j<0` which is never true and hence the loop never runs. This is why the value of `unselectedSum` is not changing in the program.

Here is an alternative approach to the problem:

```
int unSelectedSum = 0;

for(int i = 1; i<creditCard.length(); i=i+2) {

    //first we will take every even-placed digit.
    int evenDigit = Character.getNumericValue(creditCard.charAt(i));

    //next, we will multiply it by 2
    evenDigit = evenDigit*2;

    //And finally, we will add the digits to unselectedSum
    if(num/10 == 0) {
        unselectedSum = unselectedSum + evenDigit;
    }
    else {
        unselectedSum = unselectedSum + evenDigit/10 + evenDigit%10;
    }        
}
```